# kotlin, how to avoid double bang (!!) after checked the null-able for multiple variables

Tags: kotlin

kotlin code, the function

`IntegrationModehow(a: String, b:Boolean)` do not accept null-able,

how to git ride of the using of double "bang":

```
var messagingService: String? = null  //set later somewhere
var isAutoIntegration: Boolean? = null

......

if ( messagingService != null && isAutoIntegration != null) {
  val theMode = IntegrationMode(builder.messagingService!!, builder.isAutoIntegration!!)
}
```

it could use nested `let`:

```
messagingService?.let { messagingService ->
    isAutoIntegration?.let { isAutoIntegration ->
        val theMode = IntegrationMode(messagingService, isAutoIntegration)
    }
}
```

but is there suggested way for this type null-able checking?

Comment: If they don't accept nullable, then don't accept them. Throw an exception for invalid input, and fix the code that incorrectly uses it.

Comment: you are checking that `messagingService ` is not null, then using `builder.messagingService`. If you want to not have to use `!!`, then simply change the `if` to check `builder.messagingService != null`

Comment: Or, better yet, do `val theMode = IntegrationMode(messagingService, isAutoIntegration)`?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You've got `val messagingService: String? = null  //set later somewhere` - this can't be true, if it's a `val` you can only set it once. You've already set it to `null` so you can't change it to something else later. Please show exactly where these are declared, and exactly where they are set. Are they at top level? Properties in a class? Variables in a function?

Comment: @k314159, thx! it should be `var` in the sample.

Answer (score 1):

I presume `messagingService` and `isAutoIntegration` are `var` properties in a class. Therefore, their values can be changed by another thread between the time you check them and the time you use them. To prevent this, your own suggestion of using `?.let {...}` is perfectly fine. But if you don't like the look of that, you can assign them to local variables, which the Kotlin compiler knows are guaranteed not to change:

```
val messagingService = builder.messagingService
val isAutoIntegration = builder.isAutoIntegration
if (messagingService != null && isAutoIntegration != null) {
    val theMode = IntegrationMode(messagingService, isAutoIntegration)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
with(builder) {
    if ( messagingService != null && isAutoIntegration != null) {
        val theMode = IntegrationMode(messagingService, isAutoIntegration)
    }   
}
```

Comment: using the `with(builder)` the `IntegrationMode(messagingService, isAutoIntegration)` still get compiler error.

Comment: Sorry, I should have paid attention to the scope of 'builder'. The idea would be to check if your params are null. As user k314159 did

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**